# Powershell reg enquiry and table formation

Tags: powershell

```
$array = @()
$path="C:\Reports\Software.txt"
$programs = Get-Content -Path $Path;
foreach ($program in $programs) 
{
$system64=Get-ItemProperty 
HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | 
Select DisplayName, DisplayVersion | where {$_.DisplayName -like 
"*$program*"};
$system32=Get-ItemProperty 
HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*  | Select 
DisplayName, DisplayVersion| where {$_.DisplayName -like "*$program*"};

if ($system64)
{
Write-Host "npp query = "$system64""
Write-Host "npp query = "$system32""
Write-Host -ForegroundColor green "$program already installed!"

        $array += $system64
}
elseif ($system32)
{
Write-Host "npp query = "$system64""
Write-Host "npp query = "$system32""
Write-Host -ForegroundColor green "$program already installed!" 
$array +=  $system32
}
else
{
$array +=  $program
}
}
$array |Export-Csv C:\Reports\Software.csv -NoType
```

I am trying to create a table with specific software I have on my computer and their Version.

I would like if the Software doesn't exit to put software name under the header DisplayName and under the header DisplayVersion to put Not Installed.

It works fine if the software exists but if it doesn't it doesn't put the name under the header and put a blank line on the excel file.

example what I am taking now is :

```
DisplayVersion DisplayName                                              
Gimp            2.8.22
7-Zip           18.01

Notepad++       7.5.8
```

What i Want

```
DisplayVersion DisplayName
Gimp            2.8.22                                                     
7-Zip           18.01
Adobe Acrobat   Not Installed                       
Notepad++       7.5.8
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: Why do you use `$array +=  $_.program`? Shouldn't it be just $program?

Comment: So yes it was the last attempt to try to fix but yes the code initial is withoyt $_ I will edit it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this one a try in your else statement:

```
$array += @(1 | Select-Object @{Name="DisplayName";Expression={$program}},@{Name="DisplayVersion";Expression={'not installed'}})
```

With this, you create a custom object and add it to your array.

Hope it helps.